# How to get all followers from ListFollowers() method of TweetSharp Library using wpf?

Tags: wpf, api, twitter, tweetsharp

I am developing a demo application using TweetSharp Library and wpf and i want all followers of my users.

I'm using ListFollowers() method of TweetSharp library but it gives only 20 followers.

Help please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use NextCursor parameter in ListFollowers() method like this:

var followers =  service.ListFollowers(new ListFollowersOptions { Cursor = -1});

while (followers.NextCursor != null)

{

followers = service.ListFollowers(new ListFollowersOptions { followers.NextCursor });

//your code here.

}

Hope this will solve  your problem.